# confirm bitcoin node on bitnodes.io

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, port, umbrel

The Bitcoin Core 25 App has just finished syncing 100% on the Umbrel node. Within the App I confirm seeing new Bitcoin blocks arrive. Not sure why bitnodes.io shows the following message:

{IP Address} is unreachable.

Additional info:

1. Connected to Nord VPN service at my home router
2. Ports 8333 are open at my home router
3. Port forwarding is enabled for 8333

Answer (score 2):

Nord VPN does not support port forwarding: https://support.nordvpn.com/FAQ/1047408432/Do-you-offer-port-forwarding.htm

Comment: Besides bitnodes is there another service that can help confirm a functioning node outside of the Umbrel Bitcoin app?